# Timeout elapsed? by WaitForExit

Tags: c#, timeout, waitforexit

How do I know if the time limit has expired or the process was terminated by the user?

```
Process p = Process.Start(this.EmergencyApp, npLang);
p.WaitForExit(this.Timeout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WaitForExit()` [returns a boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   true if the associated process has exited; otherwise, false.

Comment: Oh, I saw only the call without parameters. This is void. That is why I have seen over the return type bool. Thank you!!!

Comment: You must observe something here! If the process is already running, WaitForExit will complete immediately with a true

Comment: And another thing! Before calling the WaitForExit, WaitForInputIdle should be called. http://support.Microsoft.com/kb/305369/en-us